# PostgreSQL Transactions Using Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, transactions

Hey guys so I created a method that generates some data by creating a PostgreSQL Temp Table and then using this in another query. My question is, if multiple clients are calling this function will I be creating and dropping my temp table multiple times in one transaction? Or is each ActiveRecord connection call I make an entirely separate transaction? To elaborate further here is my code:

```
TEMP_TBL_NAME = "temp_tbl"

def self.generate_exclusions(rules, base_query, rule_attrs)
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #{TEMP_TBL_NAME};")

  # create a temp table with all rule fields
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    "CREATE TEMP TABLE #{TEMP_TBL_NAME} AS #{base_query}")

  qs = rules.map do |rule|
    self.rule_query_instance(rule, rule_attrs)
  end.compact.join(" UNION ")

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(qs).to_a
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #{TEMP_TBL_NAME};")
end 
end
```

So once again if multiple clients are calling this method, does each instance of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(blah blah blah) create an entirely new transaction? And if each transaction is in fact separate then I would not have to worry about multiple clients using the method correct? If these are all one transaction that is created before hand, then how do I best handle the issue of multiple clients constantly creating and deleting this temp table in one transaction?

Also I assume I could improve my code by adding an ON COMMIT DROP to my CREATE TEMP TABLE query so that I do not have to check for existence to drop each time, instead dropping at the end of the transaction.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe it will only be executed once and rollback if failed. Although you probably want to use some unique table name for each client request. I would suggest generating a random number to append to table name.

Comment: Ya I was just thinking of that good idea, I will need to pass the table name as a parameter to another method using it in that case though otherwise another client could seemingly update it before it is read

Comment: And when you say only executed once does that mean every time a new client calls generate_exclusions an entirely new transaction is made on the first ActiveRecord call? Is each ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute() its own transaction?

Comment: It seems quite strange to me to create a temp table, populate it, query it, then tear it down during a web request. Can you elaborate on the higher level objective this is intended to achieve?

Comment: I am using this temp table so that I can say something like SELECT * FROM (TEMP_TABLE) WHERE (*whatever clause I am appending on). Is there a better way to do this? I have this temp table because my base_query is very large and I need to use it to query many times.